# CSS button size different in Firefox 19 (works in chrome and IE9)

Tags: css, forms

Firefox version 19 is giving me problems with spacing between an input field and a button. I would like the input button to appear to be inside the form background, and vertically centered, but the button is larger in Firefox than in Chrome or IE9 so it touches with the bottom of the form background. I am seeing this on a 1600x900 display. It looks fine on Chrome and IE9. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gyFS4/1/

HTML

```
<div id="signUp">
    <form action="" method="post" id="signup">
        <input type="text" class="left" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" value="">
        <input type="submit" id="notify-me" class="button" value="Sign me up!">    
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
form {
    width: 406px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 32px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

#email {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #202020;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

#email:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: #c3d753;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #c3d753), color-stop(100%, #a7ba3f));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3d753, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3d753, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c3d753, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c3d753, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #c3d753, #a7ba3f);
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:1px solid #82922d;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; 
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding:8px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #daf159;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #daf159), color-stop(100%, #a7ba3f));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #daf159, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #daf159, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #daf159, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #daf159, #a7ba3f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #daf159, #a7ba3f);
}
.button:active {
    background-color: #c3d753;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #a7ba3f), color-stop(100%, #c3d753));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a7ba3f, #c3d753);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a7ba3f, #c3d753);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a7ba3f, #c3d753);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a7ba3f, #c3d753);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a7ba3f, #c3d753);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset       0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset    0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:inset            0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: I added the live link, but I'll add jsfiddle too.

Comment: I substituted the live link for a jsfiddle. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/gyFS4/1/

Comment: It looks fine on my version of Firefox 19. Are you running a Windows build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a height and width on `.button` class.

```
.button {
    ...
    width:125px;
    height:40px;
}
```

The above looks good to me. Adjust to your tastes.

http://jsfiddle.net/gyFS4/10/

Comment: Without specifying widths and heights you are depending on the browser to paint the object with its 'best guess' and each browser is different. When you tell the browser the exact width and height there is no question. Every standards complaint browser will paint the object the same every time. For exact same placement always remember margin and padding, which you did.

Comment: Ahhh thanks silly mistake. The text seems like it's off (1 pixel vertically lower in firefox than in chrome) but it looks good, thanks.

Comment: The text issue is likely a font thing. Don't forget to select and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    form {
    padding: 0px 0px 3px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your site in Firefox 19 and it looked fine. But that maybe because my browser picked a font as I don't have the "Open sans" font on my computer.

Usually the problem you're describing is caused by the parent elements width being too small. Make sure you are adding each child elements width and both sides of all margins, borders, and padding. And as the button is being auto sized based on the font you may want to use firebug's "Layout" tab to see what the actual size of the button is. Also to avoid the font problem use a font that is on all computers, or use "@font-face" to give the visitors computer the font it needs to use (as long as the font isn't copyrighted).